# mouse movement from div to div, don't hide div that is not wrapped inside parent on parent's mouseleaving - jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hide, positioning

The following is happening:

Two divs,

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>

  <div onmouseover="$(this).next('#mydiv').show();" onmouseleave="$(this).next('#mydiv').hide();" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:#000000;color:#ffffff;">hover</div>
  <div id="mydiv" onmouseleave="$(this).hide();" style="display:none;">content</div>
```

My problem,

```
$(this).next('#mydiv').hide();
```

on mouseleave is causing the inability to focus on the second div, I need for the second div to hide when mouseleave occurs of the first div making the trigger only if the mouse hasn't entered into the second div after leaving the first div, such a dilemma.

I am working with a plugin for a tooltip and can't afford to wrap the second div inside the first one which would be a solution but a bigger problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't change the way you implemented the jquery but you should change into external fie

see http://jsfiddle.net/bp6Gv/

```
<div onmouseover="$(this).next('#mydiv').addClass('active');" onmouseleave="$(this).next('#mydiv').removeClass('active');" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:#000000;color:#ffffff;">hover</div>
  <div id="mydiv" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('active')" onmouseleave="$(this).removeClass('active');" >content</div>
```

CSS

```
#mydiv {
   display: none;
}
#mydiv.active {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, doesn't work on Chrome on the fiddle [will test locally], thanks so much.